# Is there any (free) alternative to Visustin, I need to create flowcharts from existing JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, flowchart

Basically, I need to convert existing JavaScript code to flowcharts, I've tried using Code Visual to Flowchart but it doesnt produce the flow charts how I would like them to (just shows links to the different functions...

Whereas Visustin actually separates each function automatically.

Is there any free alternative or even a lesser expensive software?

Answer (score 4):

I think converting the code unedited results is useless due to too much detail. I would suggest a different approach that yields very readable flowcharts. http://code2flow.com creates flowcharts from C-like (or Javascript-like) pseudo-code which can contain arbitrary natural language. Please note that I am directly involved with this solution. You should probably create a different flowchart for each important function in your code.

Sample flowchart (you may click to edit)
[image]

Comment: If he is going to manually build them, he might as well use GraphViz. It is free, open source, and he can use it on his own machines. Not outside connection necessary, once he's got the package installed.

Comment: Sure, but note that in graphviz you have to define each node and each connection manually. In the end it's more work.

Comment: Simple google search for "Pseudocode to Graphviz" yielded the following result:

https://gist.github.com/antimatter15/1841460

Comment: The original poster was questioning converting existing JavaScript into flowcharts. I am currently looking at solutions for 3700 VBScript files, and I do not like the look of Visutin but do like the functionality. I took a parser/converter and modified it (+2 hrs) to convert them all in a legible manner and have tested a few through Code2Flow in comparison to the Visutin and they are diagrammed the same but more legible and better looking in Code2Flow..

Comment: Nice @Kaylus, could you share some example comparison?